# GUI testing in the background

Tags: automation, gui-testing

I am using a python script to control the mouse and keyboard and simulate an user in a GUI application in Linux.

The problem is that the script requires the computer to be idle, and I can't do other things while it is running, so I let it running during the night.

I would like to run multiple instances of this script in the background at the same time, in the same computer, without it interfering with my physical mouse and keyboard.

I tried to use multiple virtual machines and run one script per VM, but it starts to slow down with more than two VMs.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xephyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr) and the older [Xnest](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xnest) are leight-weight alternatives to full blown virtual machines if it comes to running applications on the same desktop with separated X servers.

Whether the keyboard and mouse test interactions will replay independently enough depends on the setup configuration and your test tool's style of user input emulation.

Comment: I tried Xnest and it worked for some applications, but the application I am using failed to start GLX. I tried Xnest :1 +iglx but it didn't help. Do you know how I can use GLX in the nested xserver?

Comment: I tried Xephyr and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!